# Error : showing "all" does not exist when trying to make the makefile

Tags: linux, windows, makefile

I am an absolute beginner in this field and am currently modifying the windows makefile to run on linux, i am using jenkins for the automation and it has following pseudocode.

`makefile`:

```
PROJECT=abc.exe
UNITS=$(BOXUNIT)\xyzcom
EXEREF=C:\Program files\common\$(PROJECT)

all:xyz
xyz:
        @"$(MAKE)" $(MFLAGS) TARGET=WIN32\Release\$(PROJECT) binary

%include ../../boxunit/file.mak
```

This code calls file.mak which has pseudocode ..

`file.mak`:

```
PLATFORM:=$(TARGET,D,D)
CONFIG:=$(TARGET,D,B)
NAME:=$(TARGET,B)
EXT:=$(TARGET,E)
```

and the remaining code all depends on these values.

To run the makefile in linux i have made the following changes and have created the needed directories.

```
PROJECT=abc
UNITS=$(BOXUNIT)/xyzcom
EXEREF=/home/common/$(PROJECT)

all:xyz
xyz:
        "$(MAKE)" $(MFLAGS) TARGET=LINUX64/Release/$(PROJECT) binary

include ../../boxunit/file.mak
```

when i make the file, the TARGET value is not being assigned to the values in file.mak file.
Instead the PLATFORM,CONIFG, etc values are blank and i am getting errors like "all" does not exist and "xyz" does not exist.

It will be really helpful to know, what i am doing is right or wrong and to know if there exists any other better approach to do this.

Any help on this is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing I would do is add a space before `all` depedency list : `all:  xyz`. (Even if it doesn't really matter) Next, adding a line between `all` and `xyz` should change the error.

Comment: Also you may consider adding a `.PHONY`. Something like that `.PHONY: all xyz`

Comment: How unusual.  `make` is not a conventional tool for Windows projects.  It is much more common that one tries to adapt a POSIX makefile to a Windows `make` than the other way around.

Comment: The problem appears to be the syntax of `file.mak`.  I'm not sure what `$(TARGET,D,B)` is supposed to mean, for example, but I don't recognize the syntax, unless it is meant to access a variable named "TARGET,D,B".  What `make` implementation are you using on Windows?

Comment: First you haven't set `BOXUNIT` variable.  Second, it looks like the original makefile was an nmake makefile, not a make makefile.  nmake is not make.  If you want to translate an nmake makefile to make you'll need to understand the special things nmake does, such as (as mentioned by John Bollinger) this special syntax with commas in variable names.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion a single error was removed, will try the next suggestion. Thank you for pointing out the error. @Julio.G

Comment: The project was intially built in windows and deployed to linux server. At present i am trying to build it in linux itself. so not sure how it works....The syntax means it will extract the binary file from directory it is for omake files in windows. @JohnBollinger ... Will look into the proper syntax to acheive in linux makefiles. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @MadScientist will look into how the nmake works.  will Set the BOXUNIT variable and try again.